# Dynamically make certain elements droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I'm making a scheduling webapp. I have a table as a calendar with cells (`class="dtime"`) as timeslots during the various days of the week.

The list of clients is underneath. On hovering over a name, cells within the calendar turn red (can't schedule the client here) based on known time conflicts using `toggleClass`. The names will be dragged into the calendar and dropped on non-conflicting timeslots to 'schedule' the client ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azmanam/weTv6/2/)).

I only want the non-conflicting timeslots to be droppable. but the cells with the 'conflict' class change with each client, and are only attached while hovering over a client's name.

**My question:** How can I make all cells without the 'conflict' class droppable, when the 'conflict' class a) doesn't exist on `$(document).ready()`, and b) changes dynamically based on mouse position?

I tried using `$('.dtime').not('.conflict').droppable()`  in `$(document).ready()` but that didn't work because, again, none of the cells have the 'conflict' class when the page is loaded, and won't until a client name is hovered.

The closest I can get ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azmanam/weTv6/2/)) is to make all timeslots droppable and set rules on `over`, `out`, and `drop`. Within each setting, it tests for the 'conflict' class, then changes cell color to show the timeslot is 'acceptable' (`over` and `out`, mimicking `hoverClass`), and either schedules the client or returns without doing anything (`drop`). This works, **but** a) it seems like there should be a better way, and b) if you move the mouse into the cell *too quickly*, it doesn't catch the 'conflict' class and turns green anyway, then stays green if you try to drop it.

You can see my other attempts of timing the initiation of the droppable in the commented-out code in the jsfiddle. Nothing works perfectly.

Can you show me how to dynamically make certain elements droppable, or show me another way entirely to accomplish what I want?

Comment: did you try using `droppable('destroy')` in mouseleave handler of `hover()`? See [dropable docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Comment: @charlietfl adding the `droppable('destroy')` to hover's mouseleave returns "Error: cannot call methods on droppable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'". Error persists even when I move the droppable initiation into the hover mouseenter handler

Comment: you likely need to narrow selector target to only elements that have droppable initialized on

Comment: this seems to work, thanks :) Only buggy issue remaining is the hoverClass seems to only work intermittently, and appears to be dependent on the speed of moving the mouse. Are my initializations in the wrong place? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azmanam/weTv6/6/)